# Is it correct to say "wind something secure"?

Tags: word-choice

Let's say there is a doorknob that is wobbly, and I want it be fixed. Can I say this?

> I will try to **wind** the doorknob secure today.

Or would it be to say it this way?

> I will try to **tighten** the doorknob today.

Tell me please the most natural way to say that?

Comment: The first does not make much sense, the second is correct.

Comment: If the first one did make sense semantically, you would still want to use the *adverb* ***securely*** rather than the *adjective* secure. Or use "so that it is secure" instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Winding" the doorknob, in this instance, would be synonymous with "turning", and would be associated with opening the door. However, nobody uses that word in this context, so the reader would be confused.

Winding, when referring to physical objects and not people's emotions, is usually only used in one of a couple of different instances: 1) when referring to springs, particularly of clocks, and it denotes turning something over and over again to store potential kinetic energy which is slowly released over time to drive the gears that move the hands of said clock; and 2) wrapping a cord or a rope around something like a pole or a tent stake.

If the doorknob is loose, then usually it's not the problem with the doorknob, but with how it's fastened to the door. With that in mind, I would rewrite the sentence to refer to however the doorknob is fastened to the door (usually be screws) and tightening those to make it less loose.

Comment: You also wind cord *around* things, and where the around (what what it is around) is implicit it may be omitted.

Comment: doorknobs are not wound.

Comment: @Lambie Unless they're tied to a string and wrapped around a door frame. ;) But, yes. Contrived examples aside, doorknobs are not capable of being wound—only of being turned.